# JQuery Datepicker and my own Timepicker combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have got a combined plugin: `JQuery Datetimepicker` and my own `Timepicker` in one javascript file.

The problem is when I click on `JQuery Datetimepicker` button my `Timepicker` does not close. I have tried to search for `JQuery Datetimepicker` button's class `.ui-datepicker-trigger` and `addEventListener` on it but it did not work.

Also, in my code, I have got an event when `document.onclick` my `Timepicker` closes and this part of code works good.
Please, give me a hint, how can make my `Timepicker` close when clicking  `JQuery Datetimepicker` button?

Best regards,
Sveta

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community. Please edit your post to add some code so we can understand better your issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you shared no code to go by, here is a functional date and time picker with many options you can use as reference in what's wrong with your code.

DEMO: [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/kensoubf/)

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="escolhe_data"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        },
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
      }
    });
});
```